# .Net.Mail (4.0) smtpClient timeout if over 50 receivers

Tags: c#, smtp, .net-4.0

I use net.Mail to try send email with 50 recipients which has 200s timeout in the settings. 
Press send email button and it receives a timeout exception. I wonder whether smtpclient has an issue of limit on maximum no. of recipients. 
Or smtpClient has some other factors that that affect performance of sending one email to 50 recipient, it may not have ssl, e.g. SMTP server hardware, firewall. 
I hope someone can provide info for my acknowledgement. Thanks

```
protected void sendEmail(string strTo)
{
        string strFrom = "abc@test.com"
        string strSubject = "Some text for you emailbody";

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(strFrom);
        mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
        mailMessage.Subject = strSubject;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtpServer", 25);
        smtpClient.Timeout = 200;

        mailMessage.Body = strSubject;
        mailMessage.To.Add(strTo);// * 50 recipients
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
 }
```

Comment: Looks like the smtp server url is missing at least in your example. I think it could be in a config file or passed in via SmtpClient constructor

Comment: @awright18, Thanks for reply, but the main point I ask is whether there are limitation on max no of receivers in sending one email